# No such file or directory even though it is set to write mode. How to fix this problem and how can I properly do it?

Tags: python, discord.py, programming-languages

So I'm trying to generate a text document in Python and I want the generated file to be uploaded. However, even if I set the function to write mode, I get this error:

[image]

Code (text_document_generator.py):

```
import os

def writeToAndUploadFile(filename, filecontents): # This function generates the text file and returns the file name.
    path = "text_documents/"
    textfile = open(os.path.join(path, filename + ".txt"), "w")
    textfile.write(filecontents)
    textfile.close()
    return textfile.name
```

Code (main.py):

```
@client.command(aliases = ["newtextdoc"])
async def new_text_doc(ctx, filename, *, filecontents):
    await ctx.send("Text document successfully generated.")
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(text_file_generator.writeToAndUploadFile(filename, filecontents)))
```

If this is obvious, sorry. I'm slightly new to making apps in Python. I've done os.path.join as well but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: does the folder ```text_documents``` exist? python doesnt make folders automatically

Comment: yes apparently it does

Comment: what happens if you do os.open instead of open?

Comment: @spadel is that a rhetorical question?

Answer (score 0):

The text file dosen't seem to be created, then use:

```
textfile = open(os.path.join(path, filename + ".txt"), "w+")
```

The text file will be created automatically if does not exist.